# Euler equation - Assignment Differential Equations and Numerical Methods

Tags: numerical-methods, euler-lagrange-equation

I don't know how to approach this question by numerical methods, any help will be appreciated:

I need to solve the following differential equation using numerical methods

[formula I was given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EIEX.png)

(I can't embed images yet)

> $$
> \frac{dx}{dt} = ω\sqrt{A − x^2},
> $$
>   where $A, ω > 0$ and $x = x_0$ at $t = 0$.
>
> It is to be solved from $t = 0$ to $t = 50.0$. It has analytical solution $$x(t) = \sqrt{A} \sin(ωt + φ),$$ where $\sin(φ) = {x_0 \over \sqrt{A}}$ if $x_0 ≤\sqrt{A}$.

The question I am trying to solve is the following

> *Rewrite the differential equation you have been given at the start
>   of this document in the correct form for applying the Euler and
>   Euler-Cauchy numerical schemes. Write down an appropriate
>   1
>   Euler method recursive scheme to solve this differential equation
>   for the following values of the parameters and initial conditions:*

- $ω = 3.1$, $A = 10.0$, $x_0 = 2.0$.

Comment: Thanks @Moo, I have looked at similar sites but failing to understand which of the two formulas I was giving, that I should be using. 

Also, I can't find an example which contains a √  this is confusing me, as I don't know where to start the equation

Comment: You seem to have written the source for your image yourself. You can just copy it here and it should be displayed by the mathjax javascript library. It is easier to adapt the code than to translate the image from scratch.

Comment: What is the Euler-Cauchy numerical scheme? I know Euler-Cauchy differential equations, which this one is not,...

Comment: hi @Dr.LutzLehmann, I add the equation in text,

Comment: @Dr.LutzLehmann, thanks for editing the equation

Comment: What is the context of this task, what is meant with "rewrite"? Note that the derivative has to be positive, so that the given function is only a solution as long as it is growing. This will not extend to $t=50$. The domain of the ODE has a boundary at $x=\sqrt{10}$. The solution will touch this boundary, explicit methods especially have a problem in staying inside the domain in such situations. One could use an odd extension of the square root to extend the domain,...

Comment: Hi @Dr.LutzLehmann, What I assume the "rewrite" means, is to manipulate the equation to suit it to the Euler method.

Comment: But it is already in explicit first order form. There is nothing to manipulate in that regard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100929/discussion-between-user3292394-and-dr-lutz-lehmann).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right side of the ODE is always positive, so that the given function is only a solution as long as it is growing. After reaching the maximum it will stay constant at this maximum value $\sqrt{A}$.

---

The Euler method computes 
$\newcommand{\D}{\mathit{\Delta}}$
$$
\D x=f(t,x)\D t\implies x_{n+1}=x_n+f(t_n,x_n)\D t
$$
Note that this formula does not detect and handle domain boundaries. 
However, the domain of the given equation is bounded by $|x|\le\sqrt{A}$. Just applying the method without further preparations will run into errors in computing square roots of negative numbers.

There are some natural continuations of the square root that remove this domain limitation, like
$$
\dot x=ω\sqrt{\max(0,A-x^2)}~~\text{ or }~~\dot x =ω\,{\rm sign}(A-x^2)\sqrt{|A-x^2|}.
$$
The numerical solutions by the Euler method will reach this fixed point $x=\sqrt{A}$ and step over it. In the first variant the solution will then stay constant, in the second variant it will oscillate around the fixed point, possibly quite chaotically due to the vertical tangent at $x=\sqrt{A}$.

This can be repaired to some degree by replacing the vertical tangent by a segment with a steep but finite slope,
$$
\dot x=ω\frac{A-x^2}{\sqrt{\max(\varepsilon,|A-x^2|)}}.
$$